# Arduino Uno + cc3000 breakout board - read DOM instead of HTML

Tags: arduino-uno

Is there a way to make the CC3000 read the DOM of a website instead of the HTML on the file?

I'm using the WebClient file which works fine and prints the HTML of the webpage, but the website I'm trying to read from has its HTML different from its DOM (ie: Javascript modifies the HTML once the page loads).

Can I use something other than `www.read()`?

Answer (score 1):

To get a (programatically changed) DOM you need an HTML parser to construct the initial DOM (and something that runs Javascript to modify it).

The server only sends a file and does not store or send a DOM; a DOM is built by the receiving application, usually a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is something related to browsers. A web server merely serves up stored HTML and any accompanying JS to the client CC3000. It's up to a browser to parse the document, execute any JS to construct the DOM tree and finally render the webpage based on the DOM--not something an Arduino is built for.

I'm not an expert but you will have to forward the HTML from your Arduino to a browser and then somehow scrape the results after it renders the page. Or use a website that implements server-side rendering.